# Animation*asState - trigger target state change after composition

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am currently struggling with Jetpack Compose possibility to animate objects.

I use `animate* asState` and it works fine, but one thing i can't accomplish: To create an enter-transition.

Basically, I just want to start an animation when my composable is shown for the first time. But the `animate*asState` only allows to modify the target value (not the initial one).

One solution i thought of, was to change the target value at the end of the composition. But I think there has to be a better way

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Animatable](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#animatable), which lets you specify an initial value, and then you call animateTo() to redirect to a target value (canceling any in-progress animation as well).